# copy file from one server to another in linux

Tags: linux, shell

how to run commands like ftp or sftp or scp in background? Also how to setup password less connection for running these command?

Comment: This is explained in the documentation of the commands. I assume you read their manual page. So what in there specifically don't you understand?

Comment: Also, how to use google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for manual pages for `scp` or `rsync`, which both can do this job well, if not being forced you don't want to use `sftp` or even the non encrypted ftp file transfer!

something like the following, for example:

```
rsync [some other parameters] -e ssh SOURCE TARGET
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these commands are coming from a bash script , you would need to make sure that the two (or more ) systems have ssh certificates generated that allow you to access said systems without providing a "password" per se.

Briefly, you could do it by running this command on one system:

```
ssh-keygen
```

following through, this will generate a key. Then run:

```
ssh-copy-id user@some-remote-system
```

to copy it to the remote system, which will allow passwordless access, enabling scripts to go about their business without stalling for password prompts.